# Read file from SVN over https using svnkit

Tags: java, svnkit

SVN server is accessible over https. So I need to read a file that is located there. I followed the snippet from svnkit wiki (http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/tags/1.3.5/doc/examples/src/org/tmatesoft/svn/examples/repository/DisplayFile.java), but my `SVNKindNode` is `NONE` and as a result no file is read. Nevertheless there's no exceptions during connection. So I can assume that I do connect correctly to SVN server, but then something goes wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public class SVNRepoConnector {
    private String username = "user";
    private String password = "pwd";
    private String baseUrl = "https://mysvnserver.com/svn/project/trunk";
    private String filePath = "/myproject/src/main/webapp/file.html";

    public void downloadSchema() {
        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
        SVNRepository repository = null;

        try {
            repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(baseUrl));
            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(username, password);
            repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

            SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath(filePath, -1);

            if(nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.NONE) {
                System.err.println("There is file at: " + baseUrl + filePath);
                System.exit(1);
            } else if (nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.DIR) {
                System.err.println("The entry at " + baseUrl + filePath + " is a directory while a file was expected.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            SVNProperties properties = new SVNProperties();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            repository.getFile(filePath, -1, properties, out);

            System.out.println("Content:\n");
            try {
                out.writeTo(System.out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (SVNException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SVNRepoConnector connector = new SVNRepoConnector();
        connector.downloadSchema();
    }
}
```

I receive "There is file at..." due to SVNNodeKind equals NONE. I cannot understand what is wrong here. How to read file from SVN over https?

Btw, my svnkit is 1.8.5.

Comment: Can you check with a public file/server, so it's reproducible for others?

Comment: Yes, I tried even the sample from svnkit (link is in the message) and result is the same (they use in the example their own public svn).

Comment: http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/www/license.html gives a 404. I'm pretty sure in your case, either URL or file path is wrong. Can you see the file when accessing the complete URL in the browser?

Comment: In my case the path is correct.

Comment: @Dragon Your code in the above question is working properly..Do you know the procedure to copy an entire directory into localhost machine??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after thorough debugging of the sources.

In short, the problem is in the second argument of `repository.checkPath(filePath, -1);` and `repository.getFile(filePath, -1, properties, out);`. `filePath` must be file name and path to it must be in the `baseUrl` field. After these changes everything started working correctly.

Regarding the snippet, in case of `www/license.html`, one should pass `1` as a second arg.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a relative path (unless `baseUrl` is the repository root):

```
private String filePath = "myproject/src/main/webapp/file.html";
```

instead of

```
private String filePath = "/myproject/src/main/webapp/file.html";
```